# How am I able to set 2 images to overlay one another

Tags: css, html

I have set the following style settings to create an overlay effect. However, I am not really getting the desired overlay effect, have I done anything wrong. Could anyone please help.

***Code:***

```
<head>
<style>
//Set Overlay Image for Roller and Scroll
        #roller{
            position:relative;
            z-index:3;height:70px;width: 100%;
        }
        #scroll{
            position:absolute;
            z-index:4;height:650px;width: 550px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <img id="roller" src="Image/Roller.png">

        <img id="scroll" align="center" src="Image/Scroll.png">
</body>
```

Comment: Could you provide some image example? Because I'm not getting you really...

Comment: First of all, `//Set Overlay Image for Roller and Scroll` is not a valid CSS comment. use `/* COMMENT */`. Second, please provide an example of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @MaciejKwas Have updated with an image

Comment: @Daan thanks, have changed the comment and updated the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the wrong approach to this:
You shall firstly make a wrapper element that literally wraps first image, then the second image within will be positioned to this wrapper and automatically to first image, have a look below:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.bajiroo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Funny-Baby-kids-child-images-fun-bajiroo-photos-3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://www.avsworldgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/finger.png" alt="">
</div>

.img-wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
}

.img-wrapper img + img {
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:40%;
    bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3m7dad1o/

And besides: #roller is not a parent of #scroll which can't be positioned relatively to it.

Comment: so to reconfirm, the img is pointing to the first image while img + img is the second img?

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use a container around the elements you want to position.
So there is a container that has position: relative; 
Inside is the image roller, and the other one which will be placed on top with the styles:

```
<style>
    .container {
        position:relative;           
    }
    #scroll{
        position:absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
        <img id="roller" src="Image/Roller.png">
        <img id="scroll" align="center" src="Image/Scroll.png">
</div>
```

If you want these images to be Background Images, you could use multiple background images aswell:

`background-image: url(front.png), url(back.png);`